# Stable sort of 2 valued array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an array of objects. the objects have a Boolean value in them that I want to use as a key for sorting the array (all objects with true come before all objects with false) but otherwise leave things in the same order.

Is there a simple, in-place, O(n) solution to this? Maybe some variant of [radix-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)?

Comment: Here's another very similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682171/arrange-0s-1s-in-a-array

Comment: there is a slight difference in that question though, in that you are given that half the elements are 1's and half are 0's, which can help you either reduce space or time requirements a bit

Comment: Well, that's reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682171/arrange-0s-1s-in-a-array) for a discussion on this topic. You can basically have either an O(n)-solution which needs additional space or a O(n log n) in-place solution.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort. O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. With a linked list it should be feasible - you'd search for the first "false" entry and keep it as the "insertion location". (If there are no "false" entries then you're done anyway :) Then just iterate through the whole list - if you're before the insertion location and find a "false" entry or if you're after the insertion location and find a "true" entry then move it to directly before the "insertion location". So far, so `O(n)`.

Now you can convert an array into a linked list in `O(n)` and you can copy the data *back* into the array in `O(n)`. So I think it would work in terms of *complexity* - but it's not in-place. I'll think about whether it can be done in-place...