# Separate the alphabet and digit such that their relative order remains the same in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, in-place

Given an array `[a1b7c3d2]` convert to `[abcd1732]` with `O(1)` space and `O(n)` time i.e. put the letters on the left and digits on the right such that their relative order is the same. I can think of an `O(nlogn)` algorithm, but not better. Can somebody please help?

Comment: could you elaborate on your nlogn algorithm?

Comment: @Bartlomiej to every character assign an integer which is the character's index if it's a letter or character's index + n otherwise, where n >= size of array. Then quicksort by the assigned numbers.

Comment: Is the array always in this pairwise format? If so, the algorithm is trivial... so I suspect this might not be the case.

Comment: Also, can we count on there being an equal number of letters and digits?

Comment: I'd say the answer to both these questions is no. I would like to know the size of the alphabet though. Is it constant or O(n)?

Comment: I'm wondering - if the answer is "yes", doesn't it lead to a stable-inplace-linearithmic-comparison-only sorting algorithm, which I thought was impossible?

Comment: [Related](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=7528760). coderBon posted something which looks promising. Still trying to figure out exactly why it works and if it's really linear time.

Comment: Update: coderBon's algorithm isn't O(n), it looks like O(n log n).

Comment: Given the description `return [abcd1732]` would be a valid algorithm because the input is guaranteed to be `[a1b7c3d2]`.

Comment: I bet this is not possible to do with O(1) space and O(n) time.

Comment: That's correct. It's not. See my answer..

Comment: Does the relative order of equal letters matter? If not, you can use [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (26 + 10 is a constant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it can't be done. This is essentially a single step of the *RADIX sort* algorithm. And AFAIK stable *RADIX sort* can't be done in-place.

**edit** Wikipedia agrees with me (for what that's worth):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Stable_MSD_radix_sort_implementations

> MSD Radix Sort can be implemented as a stable algorithm, but requires
>   the use of a memory buffer of the same size as the input array

**Edit2**

If the input is always in pairs of letter-number, then the solution is quite simple, as we always know which character should go where:

```
for i=0...n/2-1
  tmp=array[i]
  if tmp is a letter 
    continue // nothing to do, we have a letter already!
  index=i
  do
    // we have the wrong think at index! Where is it supposed to be?
    if (index is even) // the wrong thing is a letter
      index=index/2
    else // the wrong thing is a number
      index=n/2+index/2
    // we found where temp should go! Lets put it there!
    // But we keep what was already there and look for its place next iteration
    tmp2=array[index]
    array[index]=tmp
    tmp=tmp2
  while index!=i
```

It might look quadratic, as for each `i` we do the `while`, but actually every element is only moved once hence it's linear.

Comment: My bad, sorry! Hadn't reloaded the comments on the other answers.

Comment: @us2012 well, you changed your comment :) Ehm - radix sort sorts bit by bit (or digit by digit). Each step sorts using a single bit (digit). Here the bit is "is this a letter or a number"

Comment: Can you reduce a single step of radix sort to exactly this problem (not simply using radix sort to do this)? If not, this answer doesn't really mean much (it just means this one way of solving it won't satisfy the requirements). There are plenty of special cases for algorithms.

Comment: @Dukeling sure. Call each value with the top bit set "digit" and each value with the top bit cleared "letter".

Comment: @JanDvorak But isn't that just using radix sort to do this, which is exactly what I said doesn't prove much - `"not simply using radix sort to do this"`.

Comment: @dukeling - then I don't understand what you mean. This is a single step of radix sort. No reduction needed...

Comment: @cluracan But it's not. It's a special case of a single step of radix sort, and, because it's a special case, anything said about radix sort doesn't really matter. It's well-known that special cases are ... special, consider NP complete problems for example - (by assumption) it takes exponential time to solve such a problem, but a special case can take as little as polynomial time (like those that work with a greedy solution for example).

Comment: @Dukeling Why is this a "special case" of a single step? How is it different than a "regular case" of a signle step of radix sort?

Comment: @Dukeling a signle step of radix sort is "choose a bit, sort by that bit". I chose the bit here to be "is it a digit". That doesn't make it a special case - and it's probably even actually the *real* case for ASCII encoding - so doing an *actual* radix sort on this list will actually do this step. And in radix sort - if you want the sort to be stable, you need O(n) memory.

Comment: @cluracan Because, for example, for an array of input size 8, we **know** that the element at index 1 has to end up at index 4 (and we also know the end index of all the other elements). If it weren't a special case, index 1 could've ended up anywhere, thus it's a special case.

Comment: @Dukeling well, we don't know that. Element at index 1 could indeed end up anywhere in this task.

Comment: @JanDvorak With radix sort, yes, but not here. Look at the example - `a1b7c3d2` -> `abcd1732`. `1` (which is at index 1) goes to index `4`.

Comment: @Dukeling it seems you are assuming the array always in this pairwise format (such as in the example). As far as I understand it - that isn't the case here. There is no reason whatsoever for element 1 to always get to 4. However, if that is indeed the case then the question is trivial.

Comment: @Dukeling if the array was always in pairwise format, then the task is trivial (well, easy)

Comment: @JanDvorak I disagree. What would the algorithm be? An exact reverse of this question was asked [here](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=7528760), doesn't look like anyone got an O(n) solution.

Comment: @Dukeling that would be a static permutation, dependent only on the array size. The non-trivial part would be to find an execution plan to perform the permutation. In essece, to find and encode the cycle space for a particular sequence of permutations.

Comment: I'll stand by my assumption that this question is asking about the so-called "pairwise format" (which doesn't seem all that trivial to do for any size input - feel free to convince me otherwise). At least until the ask-and-disappear OP clarifies.

Comment: @Dukeling I admit, the "trivial" was a strong word, but compiling a list of cycle spaces is definitely easier than the unrestricted problem.

Comment: @Dukeling the map is (x=>(x/2)mod(max-1)) (max maps to itself). A little math in the Z_(max-1) field yields the cycle size. What's left is to find all cycle starts fast enough and with O(1) memory.

Comment: @dukeling - just edited the solution to solve the case of pairs.

Comment: I doubt your code will work, or it's not linear, but I'm through arguing about things or thinking particularly hard for today.

Comment: @dukeling - I tested it quite a lot - from n=2 to n=1000. It works. It's very short you can test it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is really a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682171/arrange-0s-1s-in-a-array), just stated a bit differently.

(Since your problem could really be considered a stable 0-1 sort)

Unfortunately I can't figure out the algorithm, nor find any simple pseudocode, but if you'd like the algorithm is descibed here: http://www.diku.dk/~jyrki/Paper/KP1992bJ.pdf

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference, if only because not all of us have a PDF reader.

Comment: @JanDvorak And because links break, and we don't really want to read a 6 page document to find the answer.

Comment: @Dukeling yeah... I didn't want to restate what was already in the meta post

Comment: Sorry. I'll see if I can find a shorter description then.

Comment: Read the article. I won't say that I understood everything - but they do "cheat". By "cheat" I mean they use `log(n)` counters (making the memory `O(log n)` BUT they bit-pack these counters (they are small enough) so they only take `O(1)` counters (each with `log(n)` bits).

Comment: If it's a duplicate, instead of just stating it in an answer, vote/flag to close as such.

Comment: Nope, couldn't find a more concise explanation, or pseudocode that seems to work, so I'll just leave the reference to the paper in the answer. Goodnight, gentlemen.

Comment: @JanDvorak ok then. Didn't find it out at once though.

Comment: @JanDvorak however, I'm not sure if it would be obvious that it's a duplicate. Also, there does not seem to be any correct anwer to the other question, so I won't flag this.

Comment: You can post this as a comment.