# How to convert the following non-stable sorting algorithm to stable?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stable-sort

Consider n cards that are marked either red or blue

```
            i=1;
            j=n;                 
            while(i<n)
            {
              if(a[i]==RED)
                i++;
              if(a[j]==BLUE)
                j--;
              swap(a[i],a[j]);
            }
```

How to make this in-place algorithm stable I could get a O(n^2) solution to problem could anyone suggest a O(n) solution?

Comment: if `a` array holds only card colours why won't you just count them and then recreate the array by filling it with appropriate values?

Comment: @rostok That would no longer be in place, as OP has suggested.

Comment: Does this help? http://csjobinterview.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/array-stable-partition/

Comment: are we allowed to use auxiliary memory? say an array?

Comment: The simplest known solutions are rather ugly, and the O(n log n)-time divide-and-conquer algorithm is likely to be faster on current hardware anyway.

Comment: Here are links to two related or possibly duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071598/separate-the-alphabet-and-digit-such-that-their-relative-order-remains-the-same and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682171/arrange-0s-1s-in-a-array

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to use extra memory, simply do a 2 pass scan:

First pass:

```
count = 0
foreach a[i] == RED
    b[count ++] = a[i]
    i ++
```

Second pass:

```
foreach a[i] == BLUE
    b[count ++] = a[i]
    i ++
```

Finally copy `a = b`

In total, the time complexity will be `O(3n) = O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach in O(n2):

> a) append the indices of each element to the element itself.

{"RED1","RED2","BLUE3","BLUE4"}

> b) The swap function should take into account the last character, the
>   index indicator, when you try to swap two REDs or two BLUEs.

eg,: When you try to swap two REDs -> only swap if the indexOfFirst(RED) > indexOfSecond(RED)

The same way for BLUEs.

Note: You will need to add some extra logic to find if it is a BLUE or a RED.

Answer (score 0):

Counting sort

if you have only blue and red 
you counting blue elements and red elements

```
[b1 r1 r2 b2 b3 r3 r4 b4 r5]
```

and in for loop you count yours elements 
you have `blue: 4`  `red: 5`

then you knew result table is `[ r r r r r b b b b]`
and you can know index range where is reds elements and blue elements  (last red element is *{red_count}-1*  and last blue element is *{red_count}+{blue_count}-1* ) you save this values to redIndex and blueIndex

you make second table and in for loop from end you search elements, the last is r5 its red then his index should be 4 and you decrement redIndex

```
[b1 r1 r2 b2 b3 r3 r4 b4 __] blueIndex:8 
[__ __ __ __ r5 __ __ __ __] redIndex:3

[b1 r1 r2 b2 b3 r3 r4 __ __] blueIndex:7 
[__ __ __ __ r5 __ __ __ b4] redIndex:3

[b1 r1 r2 b2 b3 r3 __ __ __] blueIndex:7 
[__ __ __ r4 r5 __ __ __ b4] redIndex:2

.....
```

The faster way to sort items O(2n) but with huge memory usage when various data