# Sorting array with Negative and Positive Integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an array which has `n` integers, It has both positive and negative integers. Now you need to sort this array in a special way so that after sorting, the negative integers should in the front and the positive integers should be in the back. Also the relative position should not be changed.

> Ex:
>   -1 1 3 -2 2
>
> Ans:
>   -1 -2 1 3 2

Write an algorithm with the following constraints `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity.

With divide and Conquer appraoch I'm coming up with `O(nlogn)` algorithm. How can we do it more better.

Comment: Isn't this what's called a "stable 0/1 sort?" Don't think there's an O(n) O(1) worst case algorithm for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682171/arrange-0s-1s-in-a-array

Comment: Seems similar to an in-place merge sort which takes *O(nlogn)* time, or a standard merge sort that takes *O(n)* space. In other words, I don't think it can be done in *O(n)* time and *O(1)* space.

Comment: I'm voted that it's a dupe of the question Gilad mentioned. It's not a literal dupe, but the difference between 0 and 1 in a struct and the sign of the integer is insignificant. For sure the best answer from @antti-huima on that question applies here exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of is the following (and it is not O(n) unless the number of negative integers is some constant number):

1. Identify regions of positive integers between 2 negative integers
2. Shift all the positive integers to the right and place the negative integer at the beginning of the region.

The complexity would be the minimum number of shifts without any extra storage. I can't think of a better strategy in O(1) space. The only other possibility is carrying out some rotation of the array to shift elements by multiple positions at a time (after counting the total number of negative elements before and after a point in an initial linear pass), but that seems like it will definitely exceed O(n) as well.

```
-1 1 3 -2 2
  |---|

-1 -2 1 3 2
     |-----|
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fully sort the array with divide-and-conquer. A single quicksort-like partition step should be enough to put the negative numbers before the positive ones and thats just O(N).

Comment: The hard part here seems to be maintaining the order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm viewing this as a state machine.

- State 1: In "seeing negative numbers" mode.  If the input is a negative number, continue in State 1.  If the input is a positive number, store the current index and continue in State 2.
- State 2: In "have seen a positive number, looking for a negative number" mode.  If the input is a positive number, continue in State 2.  If the input is a negative number, move it to the stored index from State 1 (shifting the intermediate positive numbers forward) and go back to State 1.

You move every number at most 1 time, so it's O(n) in time.  And there's only swap space and the stored index, so it's O(1) in space.

Comment: The problem is that *"shifting the intermediate positive numbers forward"* is an *O(n)* operation worst case. So this proposal is similar to an "insertion sort" or a "selection sort", both of which are *O(n^2)*.

Comment: @user3386109 Like I said, it only applies to each number at most 1 time.  It's still O(n) overall.